# preg_replace all non-digit characters except + at start of string

Tags: php, regex, replace

Assuming the input string `+123-321+123 345`, using PHP's regex functions I would like to remove all non-digit (`[^\d]`) characters, except the `+` character at the start. The `+` may or may not be present, so given the string `123-321+123 345` the result should be the same (`123321123345`).

Currently the workaround in place is to check for the `+`, then run `preg_replace('/[^\d]+/', '', $string)`, but I'm sure there must be a pure regex solution to this problem.

Thanks!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Try this

```
/(?<!^)\D|^[^+\d]/
```

`\D` is the same than `[^\d]`

`(?<!^)` is a negative lookbehind that ensures that there is not the start of the string before the not a digit.

This expression will match all non digits that are not a the start of the string.

```
preg_replace('/(?<!^)\D|^[^+\d]/', '', $string)
```

Comment: Thanks stema this is almost perfect, however it allows _any_ non-digit character at the start. I only want to allow `+`, anything else should be removed. Any way to modify your pattern for this?

Comment: I updated my answer. I added an alternation that will match the starting character when its not a plus or a digit.

Comment: Perfect, thanks for your help. Sorry I can't upvote as I'm too new but I've accepted the answer.

Answer (score 0):

Use positive lookbehind.

```
preg_replace('/(?<=\d)[^\d]+/', '', $string)
```