# Preg Replace all non numerical characters except +

Tags: php, preg-replace

I want to replace all non-numeric characters in a string except a `+`.

I've tried [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9885467/preg-replace-all-non-digit-characters-except-at-start-of-string) question, but it's not working...

Here is what I have at the moment:

```
$nn = preg_replace("/([^0-9\/+]+)/", "", $string );
```

It works 100%, except for removing the `+` in any way...

**EDIT**

My input will always contain only 1 +, and should there be more, they should be removed.

Basically, if a user enters a phone number as `(015) 234-2634` it should be returned as `+27152342634` (South African Country Code - I add the +27 at a later stage) But if `+27 (15) 234-2634` is entered, `+27152342634` should be returned.

Comment: So you want to keep exactly one `+` or all of them? Please always show your input, and expected and actual outcomes.

Comment: Are you by any chance putting this phone number in a GET parameter somewhere along the way? In that case, your `+` signs are converted to spaces. Your regex (and the ones in the answers below) would then remove that space.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You should be able to do it with the following regex:

```
[^0-9+]
```

In `preg_replace()`:

```
$nn = preg_replace('/[^0-9+]/', '', $string);
```

Your current regex also keeps a forward-slash, so to keep that functionality:

```
$nn = preg_replace('/[^0-9\/+]/', '', $string);
```

Sample code with output:

```
<?php
$string = '+27 (15) 234-2634';
$nn = preg_replace("/[^0-9+]/", "", $string );
echo $nn . "\n";
?>
```

Results in:

```
+27152342634
```

**UPDATE** (keep only first matching `+`)
Per your latest question-update, you also only want to keep the *first* `+` symbol found. To do this, since there may not be a "rule" regarding the location of the first symbol (such as "it has to be the first character in the string), I would suggest using additional methods other than just `preg_replace()`:

```
$nn = preg_replace("/[^0-9+]/", "", $string);
if (substr_count($nn, '+') > 1) {
    $firstPlus = strpos($nn, '+') + 1;
    $nn = substr($nn, 0, $firstPlus) . str_replace('+', '', substr($nn, $firstPlus));
}
```

This code will perform the original `preg_replace()` as normal and then, if there are more than 1 `+` symbols in the result, it will get a sub-string of the result up to the first `+`, then perform a string-replacement to replace all remaining `+` symbols. You could always use a second `preg_replace()` here too, but to remove only a `+` symbol it would be overkill.

Here's a [codepad](http://codepad.org/k9n5dxRb) entry for the sample.

Comment: Your answer doesn't work. It returns this error: Warning: preg_replace() [function.preg-replace]: No ending delimiter '/' found in

Comment: `$nn = preg_replace("/[^0-9+]/", "", $string );`

Comment: Must have been a typo on my side then... Regardless, that one still removes the +.

Comment: then there is some other issue... I'll have a look into it and post my findings...

Comment: Your first part works perfectly. I found an issue where I didn't encode the URL so the + was dropped

Answer (score 0):

So if you want all pluses and non-numbers removed, except for the very first `+` then you need an assertion:

```
$str = preg_replace('~  (?! ^ \+)  [^\d]  ~x', "", $str);
```

Note that I used different delimiters here `~`. And the `x` mode is for extra whitespace in the regex.

This will only work if the `+` is really the first character in your string. Is there a space before it, both will be junked.

Answer (score 0):

As i understood your problem you can use preg_replace_callback(http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-replace-callback.php) function to achive this.

**steps:**

1. Get the 3 digits with parenthesis and remove parenthesis and leading 0
2. Remove all non numeric characters(including +)
3. if it has country code just add "+" to the beginning
4. if not add "+" country_code to the beginning

```
//$string = '(015) 234-2634';
$string = '+27 (015) 234-2634';
//  \(\d{3}\)\s* to capture (015)
//  \D to capture all non numeric characters
//  ^\d{2} to capture first two digits
$pattern = array("/\(\d{3}\)\s*/","/\D/","/^\d{2}/");

echo preg_replace_callback($pattern, function($matches){
    $countrycode = 27;

    if(strlen($matches[0])>4){ //(015)
        return substr($matches[0],2,-1); //grab 15 from (015)
    }
    else if(is_numeric($matches[0]) && $matches[0]==$countrycode ){
                //if it has country code just add "+" to the begining
        return "+".$matches[0];
    }
    else if(is_numeric($matches[0]) && $matches[0]!=$countrycode ){
                //if it has not country code add "+" and countrycode to the begining
        return "+".$countrycode.$matches[0];
    }
   else{
       // if its not a digit return null
       return null; 
   }
}, $string);
```

Plase note im not a regex expert,it may have easy ways to do your task but this example works perfectly to me.